# Sql update where left join count equal to 3

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I'm trying to build a sql query where I update the value of a table where the left join of another table is equal to 3.

Example when a vehicle has 3 photos.

The query I've written thus far, it seems to fail with group by though.

```
UPDATE domain.vehicle_listing AS t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN photo AS t1 ON t0.id = t1.vehicle_listing_id
SET t0.active = 0
WHERE `create_date` >= '2015-5-2' 
AND user_profile_id is not null 
AND t0.active = 1
GROUP BY t1.vehicle_listing_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) = 3
ORDER BY create_date desc;

Vehicle_Listing
id

Photo
id, vehicle_listing_id, photo_url

OneToMany relationship with photo.
```

Comment: Provide table definitions and some sample data set better to add  [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) for sample

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I added some table deffs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is silly to use a `left join` for this.  You want `inner join`:

```
UPDATE cardaddy.vehicle_listing vl INNER JOIN
       (SELECT p.vehicle_listing_id, count(*) as cnt
        FROM photo p
        GROUP BY p.vehicle_listing_id
       ) p
       ON vl.id = p.vehicle_listing_id AND
          p.cnt = 3
    SET vl.active = 0
WHERE vl.create_date >= '2015-05-02' AND
      vl.user_profile_id IS NOT NULL AND
      vl.active = 1;
```

(Assuming that `user_profile_id` is in `vehicle_listing`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `exists`

```
UPDATE vehicle_listing AS t0 
SET t0.active = 0
WHERE t0.`create_date` >= '2015-05-02' 
AND t0.user_profile_id is not null 
AND t0.active = 1
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM photo
  WHERE vehicle_listing_id=t0.id
  GROUP BY vehicle_listing_id 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 3
)
```

Sample data for `vehicle_listing`

```
INSERT INTO vehicle_listing
    (`id`, `title`, `create_date`, `active`,user_profile_id)
VALUES
    (1, 'test', '2015-05-02 00:00:00', 1,1),
    (2, 'test1', '2015-05-02 00:00:00', 1,1)
;
```

Sample data for `photo`

```
INSERT INTO photo
    (`id`, `vehicle_listing_id`, `photo_url`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'image.jpg'),
    (2, 1, 'image.jpg'),
    (3, 1, 'image.jpg'),
    (4, 2, 'image.jpg'),
    (5, 2, 'image.jpg')
;
```

Sample Output

```
id  title   create_date             active     user_profile_id
1   test    May, 02 2015 00:00:00   0          1
2   test1   May, 02 2015 00:00:00   1          1
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c624/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE cardaddy.vehicle_listing AS t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT vehicle_listing_id, count(1) AS counter
    FROM photo
    GROUP BY vehicle_listing_id
) AS t1
ON t0.id = t1.vehicle_listing_id
AND t1.counter = 3
SET t0.active = 0
WHERE `create_date` >= '2015-5-2' 
AND user_profile_id IS NOT NULL 
AND t0.active = 1
AND t1.vehicle_list_is IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Okay, I'm taking a look at that now. I'm a little confused about your table structure. You show that vehicle_listing only has a column named ID, but it appears that you're updating a column named "active", is that correct?

Comment: Okay, I've adjusted the query in my answer and I think it should now work as expected.